# Use material design icons font instead of svg icon components

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

On the re-implementation of material-ui in the `next` branch, I've noticed that apparently the preferred way to use icons is to import components from the package `material-ui-icons`, where there's one component per each icon. I preferred the usual way of referring to components via a css class, and each css class applies the appropriate font family and character code, a-la font awesome. This makes it easier for instance, to refer to icons without having to import a component per each icon. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by importing the material design icons font in the index.html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then icons can be rendered within React jsx code like this:

```
<i class="material-icons">close</i>
```